# Control the description environment item

Tags: description

I have a very long description item to break the page boundary. How can I control the item? For example, how to make the "Very long ... Description" becomes two lines?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{description}
    \item[RC 1: Very long long long long long long long long long long long Description ] 
    The contents come here. 

    \item[RC 2: Bloomier Filters as Context Summaries] The contents come here.  
    \end{description}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `nextline` or `unboxed` styles from `enumitem`. Illustration:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

 \usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

    \begin{description}[style=nextline]
    \item[RC 1: Very long long long long long long long long long long long long long Description ]
    The contents come here.

    \item[RC 2: Bloomier Filters as Context Summaries] The contents come here.
    \end{description}

    \begin{description}[style=unboxed]
    \item[RC 1: Very long long long long long long long long long long long Description ]
    The contents come here.

    \item[RC 2: Bloomier Filters as Context Summaries] The contents come here.
    \end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]